# Why Can't I Access My Home Assistant Remotely via Nginx Proxy Manager on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, proxy, home-assistant

I'm facing difficulties setting up remote access for my Home Assistant on a Raspberry Pi 3. Feels like I've tried everything, but can't seem to get it to work. Would appreciate some help!

**My setup**

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- Home Assistant installed in a Docker container, updated to latest version
- Nginx Proxy Manager add-on installed for reverse proxy configuration
- Domain hosted by my ISP pointing to my router's WAN address
- Fetching and renewing SSL certificates using DNS challenge against DirectAdmin, with the SSL files fullchain.pem and privkey.pem located in the /ssl directory on HA

**Current Status**

- Both the local Home Assistant address (homeassistant:8123) and my domain work within my network. But not outside the network of where my HA installation is running on.
- LAN/WAN Port Forwarding: 80/80, 81/81, 443/443, all directed to the Home Assistant IP.
- No ports blocking on my router
- No firewall blocking

**Home Assistant Configuration**

In `configuration.yaml`:

```
http:
  use_x_forwarded_for: true
  trusted_proxies:
    - 192.168.10.178  # Home Assistant IP
    - [My_Public_IP]  # My Public IP
    - 172.30.32.0/23  # Docker address
    - 172.30.33.0/24  # Docker address
    - 172.30.32.3     # Docker DNS address
    - 127.0.0.1
```

**Nginx Proxy Manager Configuration**

I have created a proxy host using the Nginx Proxy Manager add-on. In the configuration, I have chosen the following settings:

- Protocol: http
- Destionation: mydomain.se
- Port: 8123
- Websocket Support enabled
- SSL: DNS Challenge DirectAdmin

**What I've tried**

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including different port forwarding configurations, ensuring there are no firewall issues, and validating my Nginx Proxy Manager configurations, but I'm still facing issues.

**Error message**

One recurring error message in the Nginx Proxy Manager logs is:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 
192.168.10.119, server: nginxproxymanager, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "homeassistant.local:81", referrer: 
"http://homeassistant.local:81/"
```

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Please let me know if there's any additional information needed.